# mysql_affected_rows not working

Tags: php, mysql

I use a mysql_affected_rows on a query but it seems to return false even though the query did execute so i'm a bit confused....

This is what i have:

```
$check = mysql_query("DELETE FROM $table 
         WHERE name = '".$darray[0]."' AND 
         password = '".$darray[1]."' AND uid = '$uid' 
         AND validation = '22'") 
         or die(mysql_error());


if(mysql_affected_rows($check)>0){
    echo 1;
    exit;

} else {
 echo 'Less than one!';
 exit;
}
```

Any idea why it says less than one - even though my query did actually delete the row ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`mysql_affected_rows()` takes the link identifier (i.e., the connection resource), not the result.

Comment: Thanks looks like you were quickest so you get the green tick ! :)

Answer (score 2):

`mysql_affected_rows` takes in a connection link, not a query. You can leave that parameter empty and it will refer to the last query executed on that connection.

Answer (score 2):

**Solved:**

Error was that mysql_affected_rows() doesn't expect the query.

More info here: http://php.net/manual/es/function.mysql-affected-rows.php

```
$check = mysql_query("DELETE FROM $table 
         WHERE name = '".$darray[0]."' AND 
         password = '".$darray[1]."' AND uid = '$uid' 
         AND validation = '22'") 
         or die(mysql_error());


if(mysql_affected_rows() >0){
    echo 1;
    exit;

} else {
 echo 'Less than one!';
 exit;
}
```

Comment: Don't know why some one would down vote this. But gave you up vote to cancel the negative vote out.